# Is continuous integration worth it for small projects?

Tags: build-process, continuous-integration, build-automation, methodology

I've been pushing for continuous integration at my company since I joined 5 months ago, but having seen the type of applications we work on I'm starting to think that it might not be worth the effort of setting up each and every project for continuous integration.

If you work in a development department where the average project takes 2-3 weeks and once it's deployed you seldom if ever have to worry about it, is continuous integration worth the hassle of setting it up?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably depends on your process. If you have unit tests that cover your code, then continuous integration is worth every bit. I'm assuming that you guys all work on a single module of work as the projects are 2-3 weeks.

I don't think folks will run every test for every one of their commits and continuous integration helps a lot here.

The other reason would be if your project is highly modularized. I've worked in systems where there are lots of modules and a developer wouldn't be functional-testing the entire website before committing. Things might not even compile properly as the other module wouldn't even build because the developer did not checkout the complete code.

I'd recommend continuous integration anyway. With setups like Hudson and Cruisecontrol, it doesn't take a lot of time to set up and pays for itself quickly.

Comment: My only experience of adding continuous integration was migrating a Huge .Net App written in .Net 1.1 to .net 2.0 and changes I had to make to the build scripts for CI were immense.

Comment: I  think itd be a problem if you write them all at one time, If you started out with a build script when you start, it shouldnt be too difficult to update it as you proceed with your migration.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I think CI and the various processes it encourages are always useful.  Getting CI setup is rather trivial once you have the server set up itself.  You're basically just copying a configuration file from one project, editing it, and creating a new project.  I wouldn't not use CI because of the "effort of setting up each and every project".

Answer (score 2):

Continuous Integration is not only a tool matter, but also a set processes (commit regularly, have a version control system...).

Concerning the I.C software, you can install, configure and start to use [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) in less than 10 minutes! So why would you go without any IC system?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how fast you can set up an automated build and then get that hooked up to a CI server.

**.NET**

I've seen us go from no automated build to an automated build for a project in a few minutes using UppercuT. We use that and CruiseControl.NET (in the configuration, we add a line per project b/c we take advantage of the preprocessor).

http://code.google.com/p/uppercut/

Some good explanations here: [UppercuT](http://ferventcoder.com/category/uppercut.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If your many apps share any common components or modules, CI and tests will likely help you notice something breaking. If they are really all little throw away, self contained scripts then you might not need CI, but it's a tough call.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, once CI is setup then adding a new project is trivial so I'd say go for it.  One benefit you're going to see is that if any of your projects *do* ever change you've already got CI and hopefully your unit tests ready to go so you won't get any nasty surprises!

Answer (score 0):

Continous Integration is not only ensuring stuff works, it also allows you to DOCUMENT and TEST the release process as it would be done by a new developer.

This ensures that the customer gets what has been tested, not what the developer just throws together from his harddisk.

This may be extremely important for maintainance purposes.