# Is Jenkins beneficial for use in smaller Project?

Tags: c++, jenkins, continuous-integration

Hi I am studying Jenkins Continuous Integration Tool and need to find its advantages .As a beginner i have explored that it helps in capturing bugs at very early stage in case of development of project of big functionality.It will build after some interval of time and will notify the concerned developers.

i have to develop a c++ application and have to decide whether to use jenkins or not?
Suppose we have a short functionality not a very large task will it be beneficial to use jenkins over there?

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/469551/395975

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even on a small project (and even if there is a single developer), setting up a CI job has benefits (not exhaustive):

1. When a CI job is set up, the developer will need to ensure that the build is reasonable and the testing strategy is usable
2. If the design is modular, the CI job will potentially fail if source control is not used properly or dependencies are not set up properly - you will want to know this ASAP
3. As the application grows, you will already have CI in place to assist the development effort along the way
4. You will know early if anyone pushes a failed build or test

Answer (score 0):

If other developers will be working with the code, it's always useful to have a separate clean machine making builds. This ensures you check in all necessary files to source control, and that the project isn't depending on some unique configuration on your dev machine.

If it's just you working on the code, I would still write some sort of build script but skip the Jenkins setup.

Comment: The additional advantage to using Jenkins is making sure that you have captured all of your build system information adequately.   By using Jenkins to build and test your code, you ensure you've captured the entire environment.

Comment: As soon as you start writing special build scripts, I think you might as well use Jenkins. It's not like there's much setup needed...

Answer (score 0):

One advantage is separation of development and automated tests. Especially in single-developer project, but equally with private brances at multi-developer project, it is IMO great relief to be just able to push new version as soon as you think it is probably fine, then continue coding. CI system will work at the same time, verifying commit by building it, running unit tests, deploying and/or creating installation packet where relevant, etc.

Definitely worth it. Doesn't even need separate build server, you can run it on your workstation. Just install, open the web UI, create job which checks out sources and runs your build commands, see how it goes.